# Data manipulation in R with data over time

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, dplyr

Based on the R data.frame below, I am looking for an elegant solution to count the number of people transitioning between groups between times.

```
dat <- data.frame(people = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
                  time = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                  group = c(5,4,4,3,2,4,4,3,2,1,5,5,4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1))
```

I would like a generalized solution as my problem is much larger in scale. I was considering that something with mutate could accomplish this but I'm not sure where to start

An example of the start of the output I am looking for would be this:

```
dat_result <- data.frame(time_start = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                         time_end = c(2,2,2,2,2),
                         group_start = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                         group_end = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                         count = "")
```

which would be repeated for all time transitions and all group transitions. Time is of course linear so 1 can only go to 2 and 2 to 3, etc. However, any group can transition to any other group including staying in the same group between times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using package `data.table` because it makes easy to work by groups. The same steps can be made using dplyr, but I'm not familiar with it.

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table:
setDT(dat)

# Make sure your data is ordered by people and time:
setorder(dat, people, time)

# Create a new column with the next group
dat[, next.group := shift(group, -1), by = people]

# Remove rows where there's no change:
# (since this will remove data, you may want to atributte to a new object)
new <- dat[group != next.group]

# Add end.time:
new[, end.time := shift(time, -1, max(dat$time)), by = people]

# Count the ocurrences (and order the result):
> new[, .N, by = .(time, end.time, group, next.group)][order(time, end.time, group)]
   time end.time group next.group N
1:    1        3     5          4 1
2:    2        3     4          3 1
3:    2        4     3          2 1
4:    2        5     5          4 1
5:    3        4     3          2 1
6:    3        4     4          3 1
7:    4        5     2          1 2
8:    4        5     3          2 1
```